# Switch tab on button clicked

Tags: java, android, kotlin, tabs, android-tablayout

I create one activity(Home activity)inside home activity I add frame layout & some buttons. in frame layout I load fragment(Home fragment)inside home fragment I create Tab Layout now my question is when we select button(from home activity)so change regarding tab is their any possible way??

Note: I can not use viewpager because of some reason

my flow is

(1) Activity->frame layout && buttons

(2) frame layout-> load fragment(Home fragment)->  tab layout->  new frame layout which contains diff. fragment regarding tabs.

when click on activity's button so change tab

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code so it's easier to understand your requirement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
yourTabLayout.getTabAt(tabPosition).select();
```

tabPosition is an `int` that determinants which tab will be selected

For example : 0 will select the first tab, 1 will select the second tab, 2 will select the third tab and so on

Comment: yaa its work for me, thanks Omar

Comment: you're welcome :) , please upvote the answer and accept it to make it easier for other people to find it